# WopiFrame.aspx download document button doesn't work when used inside iframe in a different domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps

We have a website integrated with SharePoint online and we are using WopiFrame.aspx page for previewing documents uploaded to the Sharepoint library.
The iframe has the following url: https:///_layouts/15/WopiFrame2.aspx?sourcedoc=Documents%2fpdf-sample.pdf&file=pdf-sample.pdf&action=interactivepreview.

The page looks great and shows the data we want.
However, users are not able to download the file (for example PDF) when clicking on the "Download a Copy" button.[image]
They receive a network error (blocked by response side)

It is clear that the problem is because WopiFrame.aspx page is configured with X-FRAME-OPTIONS set to SAMEORIGIN.[image]

Is there a workaround?
Or maybe there is a way to show the document without this menu?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried the same before but once i had to deal with this **X-Frame-Options** thing. See if you can set **X-Frame-Options** to below for your target site. You must be able to configure this setting in IIS for your site.

> X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thnaks Muhammad.
But the problem is that this configuration has to be made on the page which I do not control. So it doesn't work because as I understand my page (where iframe is resides in) doesn't have any control over iframe's content.

Comment: This isn't a solution as the user cannot modify IIS settings for SharePoint Online, nor Office Online.

Comment: This one is just in case he has control on the source page which he wants to show in iframe.